# UITextField cuts off descenders on Unicode characters

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextfield, unicode-string

Is there any way to get a UITextField to display an NSString containing unicode subscript characters (e.g. ₂ , ₃ ) correctly without cutting them off? I'm starting with a UITextField created in IB.

I've tried:

- setting the frame.size.height on the UITextField larger in code (just centers the cut-off characters in a taller box)
- changing the contentVerticalAlignment property to UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop- just pushes the cut-off characters to the top
- playing with the clipSubviews/ Autoresize Subviews- no effect

This is for a chemical program, so it's kinda important to see the bottom half of the numbers. Help!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to make it work for `UITextField`.

In my case I used it for placeholder texts. What worked for me was using `UILabel` for the placeholder texts. These display the subscript correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the font to a smaller size?

```
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
```

-=-=-=-=-=-

Here's a link to this same question, and they seemed to have solved it by creating a custom UILabel subclass and modifying its (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size method.

[Calling method sizeToFit on a UILabel that has subscripts is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766137/calling-method-sizetofit-on-a-uilabel-that-has-subscripts-is-not-working)

Comment: Yes- no effect. It's kinda pathological how the subscripts are scaled down to the smaller size, then faithfully chopped off again.

Answer (score 0):

Using the steps [here](http://www.andyyardley.com/2012/04/24/custom-ios-fonts-and-how-to-fix-the-vertical-position-problem/), you could edit your own custom font file you would add to your project, and increase or decrease its ascender and/or descender to allow vertical space for your subscripts.